# Usage of した時 vs. している時?

Tags: grammar, nuances, tense

> ベティーは、日本でホームステイを**した時**、スリッパの使い方になれるまで、ずいぶん時間がかかった。(from AIAIJ)

I was wondering why した時 is used. To me, this gives me the nuance of "*After* Betty did her homestay..." rather than the (I think) correct reading of "When Betty was doing her homestay..."

Is there a reason why this is preferred to using something like **している時**? The action that Betty does appears to take place *as* she is doing her homestay, not *after*, which would seem to not warrant the past tense preceding 時. Or perhaps there is a more crucial part of the sentence I misread?

Comment: I think it's better to compareした to していた than to している. Either way, it's an interesting question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. していた時
2. している時
3. した時

It depends on the related events were in a certain period of time or a moment.
We choose to say していた時 and don't think other options in this case, because it has a certain period of time. However, した時 isn't too bad, we often say this in oral, and in your case I see no problem.
Also, している時 is used when the event was **not too old in one's mind**.

For example,

> A: 爪切り持ってきてくれた?
> B: 昨日、妹に貸した時に返してもらうのを忘れた

> A: どうして帽子かぶってないの?
> B: あっ、掃除をしている時、机の上に置いままにしてた

---

Now back to your case, I think this follows almost the same tense in English but
for sure we have many exceptions.

> 私がホームステイをしていた時、金閣寺はまだ修理中でした
> 私がホームステイをした時、はじめて納豆の匂いを嗅ぎました
> 私がホームステイをした時、日本人はトイレでスリッパを履き替えるのを知りました
> 私がホームステイをしている時、スカイツリーが完成しました

All above are appropriate and interchangeable except the combination of this.

> 私がホームステイをした時、スカイツリーが完成しました

This has a nuance of 'the Skytree has been built on the day I started my home-stay'. It sounds weird but the Skytree construction doesn't depend on your travel.

> 私がホームステイをした時、みんなに正しいパンケーキの焼き方を広めました

'While I was doing my home-stay, I have introduced the proper way of making pancakes.' If you are the pancake ambassador and this sentence makes a very good sense in Japanese minds.

> オランダ人がはじめて長崎に来た時、日本人は髪の毛が赤い人もいるということを知りました

By the same token, this sentence is correct; and している時 or していた時 doesn't fit.